# Why is this derivative equal to the exponential of a matrix?

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

[In this resource](https://osupdocs.forestry.oregonstate.edu/index.php/MPM_Methods_and_Simulation_Timing) on the section `Incremental Deformation Gradient`

There is a claim that for a deformation gradient matrix $F$ then $\frac{dF}{dt} = \nabla \vec v F$. I am having some issue following the explanation that follows.

I don't understand how $F(t+\Delta t) = \exp(\Delta t \nabla \vec v) F(t) = dF \cdot F(t)$  follows from the property in the derivative.

Comment: It is a complicated way to say that $F(t) = e^{(t-t_0)\nabla\vec{v}}F(t_0)$ solves the equation, because $\nabla\vec{v}$ is a constant matrix (with respect to $t$), before rewriting it from the derivative definition in order to implement a finite element method with time step $\Delta t$, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following ODE for $y(t) \in \mathbb{R}$
$$\dot y(t) = a\cdot y(t).$$
You probably know that the solution is
$$y(t) = e^{at} y(0).$$
More specifically, one has
$$y(t+h) = e^{ah} y(t).$$
This generalizes to matrices $Y(t) \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, so consider the matrix-valued differential equation
$$\dot Y(t) = A Y(t),$$
of which the solution is
$$ Y(t) = e^{At}Y(0),$$
and again, more specifically, one has
$$ Y(t+h) = e^{Ah}Y(t).$$